# Json map into java map

Tags: java, dictionary, gson

I have the following json file

```
[{
        "en": {
            "key1": "Ap",
            "key2": "ap2"
        }
    },

    {
        "ar": {
            "key1": "Ap",
            "key2": "ap2"
        }
    }
]
```

I would like to create a Map in Java such as the key is the language (like en or ar) and the value is a object. Something like this.

```
public class Category {
    private String key1;
    private String key2;
}

    Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, Category>>() {}.getType();
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    InputStream in = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/categories.json");
    String text = IOUtils.toString(in, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    Map<String, Category> map = gson.fromJson(text, type);
```

But when I run this code, I get errors:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 3 path $[0]
```

Is my Json structure wrong or is there an easier way to map this?

Answer (score 0):

try to read this json file

```
 {
  "ar": {
    "key1": "Ap",
    "key2": "ap2"
  },
  "en": {
    "key1": "Ap",
    "key2": "ap2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The above json is collection of `JsonObject` like list or array, so just parse it to `List` of `Map` objects

```
Type type = new TypeToken<List<Map<String, Category>>>() {}.getType();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your json is a list of maps, not only maps. So you have to add it to the type declared.

Try this:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Category {
    private String key1;
    private String key2;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Category{" +
                "key1='" + key1 + '\'' +
                ", key2='" + key2 + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String json = "[{\n" +
                "        \"en\": {\n" +
                "            \"key1\": \"Ap\",\n" +
                "            \"key2\": \"ap2\"\n" +
                "        }\n" +
                "    },\n" +
                "\n" +
                "    {\n" +
                "        \"ar\": {\n" +
                "            \"key1\": \"Ap\",\n" +
                "            \"key2\": \"ap2\"\n" +
                "        }\n" +
                "    }\n" +
                "]";

        Type type = new TypeToken<List<Map<String, Category>>>() {}.getType();
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        List<Map<String, Category>> maps = gson.fromJson(json, type);
        System.out.println(maps);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input is an json array with two objects. However your target variable 'type' is a of type Object and not an 'Array of Objects'. In simpler terms, Map cannot store an 
Array.

Lets take a simpler approach to this problem(not a recommended approach). If we convert the map manually to an array of maps, that would look like this:

`yourJson -> [Map1(en,category1(Ap,ap2)),Map2(en,category2(Ap,ap2))]`

i.e. An array of Maps

So in java equivalent this becomes:

```
Type typeOfT2 = new TypeToken<ArrayList<HashMap<String, Category>>>() {}.getType();
List<HashMap<String, Category>> list = gson.fromJson(text, typeOfT2);
```

We get to what we want, but there are better ways of doing this. We need Jackson instead of Gson for this.(Some one may add a Gson based solution, pretty sure a cleaner one than above exists). Here we will use `ObjectMapper` from `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper`

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
List<Map.Entry<String, Category>> listx = om.readValue(text, ArrayList.class);
```

If you print `listx`. You can see this(overridden `toString()` of Category class):

`[{en={key1=Ap, key2=ap2}}, {ar={key1=Ap, key2=ap2}}]`

`listx` is the most accurate representation of your json and not a Map.

Now if you need a map, I will leave that as an exercise for you about how to convert your List of Map.Entry to a Map implementation.

PS.: First long answer here. Apologies for any mistakes.